# In flutter how to clear notification in bar?

Tags: flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-notifications

I am learning Google cloud messaging and [firebase messaging](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_messaging) is working fine, but when a user do not click at the notification to open the app and instead goes directly to app by manually opening it and bringing to foreground, the notification stays. I want those notification message related to my app go away when the app comes to foreground. How can I achieve this  ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It thinks there is no way to do this in [documentation](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_messaging).

But you can try this. You can just go to your MainActivity.java in your Android folder,
and do something like this.

```
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.content.Context;
```

Import these packages.

```
 @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        // Removing All Notifications
        closeAllNotifications();
    }

    private void closeAllNotifications() {
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.cancelAll();
    }
```

Add an `onResume` function below `onCreate` on MainActivity.java.

 Hope this solves your issue.

Comment: Hi, I would like to ask, how to do it for iOS ? when notification shows up on status bar, I would like to remove the badge "after" user clear notification from status bar

Answer (score 18):

Shri Hari solution did the trick.
Kotlin:

```
import android.app.NotificationManager
import android.content.Context
import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity


class MainActivity: FlutterActivity() {

    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        closeAllNotifications();
    }

    private fun closeAllNotifications() {
        val notificationManager = getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
        notificationManager.cancelAll()
    }

}
```

And For IOS I use UNUserNotificationCenter:

```
import UIKit
import Flutter
import UserNotifications

@UIApplicationMain
@objc class AppDelegate: FlutterAppDelegate {
  override func application(
    _ application: UIApplication,
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?
  ) -> Bool {

    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self)
    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
        application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0 // For Clear Badge Counts
        let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
        center.removeAllDeliveredNotifications() // To remove all delivered notifications
        center.removeAllPendingNotificationRequests()
    }
     
    return super.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
  }
}
```

Comment: How to do this in flutter 2.0? Can you please help me?

Comment: @JasminSojitra I guess it works on Flutter 2.*

Comment: This worked for me in Flutter 2.0 as well

Answer (score 4):

In case you don't want to modify your swift or java code you can use `flutter_local_notifications` which offers a method `cancelAll()`.

```
class SomeWidget extends State<SomeState> with WidgetsBindingObserver {

 @override
  void didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) async {
    if (state == AppLifecycleState.resumed) {
      await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin
          .cancelAll();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Working for me :)

Answer (score 2):

### Clear/Cancel Notifications on App Load and on Resume

#### iOS AppDelegate

Replace your `ios/Runner/AppDelegate.swift` with the following.

Just make sure any code you need for your app is also there (such as the import for Firebase and FirebaseApp.configure()).

```
import UIKit
import Flutter
import UserNotifications

@UIApplicationMain
@objc class AppDelegate: FlutterAppDelegate {
  override func application(
    _ application: UIApplication,
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?
  ) -> Bool {
    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
      clearAllNotifications(application)
    }
    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self)
    return super.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
  }

  override func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
    super.applicationDidBecomeActive(application)
    clearAllNotifications(application)
  }

  func clearAllNotifications(_ application: UIApplication) {
    application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0 // Clear Badge Counts
    let center: UNUserNotificationCenter = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
    center.removeAllDeliveredNotifications()
    center.removeAllPendingNotificationRequests()
  }
}
```

### Android MainActivity

*Note: remove all `<` and `>` in examples and use your values instead.*

Replace your `android/app/src/main/kotlin/com/<your_domain>/<your_app_name>/MainActivity.kt` with the following.

```
package com.<your_domain>.<your_app_name>

import android.app.NotificationManager
import android.content.Context
import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity

class MainActivity: FlutterActivity() {
    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        closeAllNotifications();
    }

    private fun closeAllNotifications() {
        val notificationManager = getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
        notificationManager.cancelAll()
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this package:
[clear_all_notifications](https://pub.dev/packages/clear_all_notifications)

Add package:

```
 $ flutter pub add clear_all_notifications
```

Use:

```
import 'package:clear_all_notifications/clear_all_notifications.dart';

await ClearAllNotifications.clear();
```